# Docker cannot ping local network machines by hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ping

I am transitioning my webserver and db into docker containers and using docker-compose to fire them up but encountering an issue. My container starts successfully, however, I have functions that pings other servers by `hostname` in my private network and that doesn't seem to work anymore when inside a docker container. For example:

```
ping other_hostname (cannot reach hostname inside container)
```

when I'm outside the container and ping `other_hostname` it works fine.

I did notice that when inside the container if I qualify the hostname like this:

```
ping other_hostname.home.com (this works inside the container)
```

Is there a way to ping by hostname when inside the container?

mount:

```
...

/dev/sdb3 on /etc/resolv.conf type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@/var/lib/docker/containers/13cfa734b33cda82a5e487d5a2a4b9aad2fdefaf844b49a4f92c99c4fd2089b8/resolv.conf)
/dev/sdb3 on /etc/hostname type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@/var/lib/docker/containers/13cfa734b33cda82a5e487d5a2a4b9aad2fdefaf844b49a4f92c99c4fd2089b8/hostname)
/dev/sdb3 on /etc/hosts type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@/var/lib/docker/containers/13cfa734b33cda82a5e487d5a2a4b9aad2fdefaf844b49a4f92c99c4fd2089b8/hosts)

...
```

resolve.conf:

```
~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search mydomain.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Comment: If I followed your example, check what is in `/etc/resolv.conf` in both the host and the container. Also, in the container check `mount` to see what has been added.

Comment: @KevinO So i see the mounts in my docker container, however, my `resolv.conf` in my container does not match my host. I only see `nameserver 127.0.0.11` in my container. Is there a way to be able to use my hosts `resolve.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `docker-compose.yml` example like below you can access the different services by their name. Docker will treat them as their dns name.

So in the case below it would be `mysql-service` and `gogs-service`

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./setup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret

  gogs-service:
    image: gogs
    volumes:
      - gogs-data:/data
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - "10022:22"
      - "10000:3000"

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  gogs-data:
    driver: local
```

hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add your local dns server to docker container `/etc/resolv.conf` file as

```
nameserver   dns_server_ip
```

then restart docker container.

Comment: How can I automate this in docker-compose? I checked my `resolv.conf` in my docker container but it only shows `nameserver 127.0.0.11` and not the ones on my host.